How can a Mouseclick event on an SVG Text element override the Opacity and Fill of the same element in CSS?
I'd like to add a click event on the webpage wherever the letter 'W' appears in grey, such that after a mouseclick event, the letter would stay black in that exact same space in the svg area, even after I move my mouse to anywhere else.
It's not working now in my piece of JS code, the failed addEventListener function. In the CSS-written piece of code, the style under the svg in HTML, I can only make it black for that single instance I click on the letter.
How can I achieve this in either JS or CSS?


const svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg');
const text = document.getElementsByTagName('text');

svg.addEventListener('click', () => {
    text.style.opacity = 1;
    text.style.fill = '#000000';
}); 
div {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
<div id='paper'>
  <svg version='1.1'width="595" height="842" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <style>
      .text {
          font-family: Sans-serif;
          font-size: x-large;
          fill: #D3D3D3;
          opacity: 0;
          cursor: none;
      }

      .text:hover {
          opacity: 1;
      }

      .text:active {
          fill: #000000;
          opacity: 1;
      }
    </style>

    <text x="70" y="97" class="text">W</text>
    <text x="70" y="100" class="text">W</text>
    <text x="70" y="103.5" class="text">W</text>
    <text x="70" y="107" class="text">W</text>
    <text x="70" y="110.5" class="text">W</text>
    <text x="70" y="114" class="text">W</text>
    <text x="70" y="117.5" class="text">W</text>
    <text x="70" y="121" class="text">W</text>
    <text x="70" y="124.5" class="text">W</text>
    <text x="70" y="128" class="text">W</text>
    <text x="70" y="131.5" class="text">W</text>
  </svg>
</div>




Check the console output, it should be throwing an error to guide you correctly. The getElementsByTagName returns a collection, see an example here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp
So, you must use a loop to add the event listener to all the svg elements and another loop to change every text element. I would suggest using some libraries like JQuery to make it easier to work with listeners.
I think what you want could be achieved with this code:
const svgColl = document.getElementsByTagName('svg');
const textColl = document.getElementsByClassName('text');

for (let i = 0; i < svgColl.length; i++) {
  svgColl[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < textColl.length; i++) {
      textColl[i].style.opacity = 1;
      textColl[i].style.fill = '#000000';
    }
  });
}

You could also add the event listener to the elements with text class instead of the whole svg tag.

The failed addEventListener function lets me think of putting the function into the whole svg tag, which is also failed. It should be put in the text class, as you mentioned in your last line. Thanks!

You should note:

getElementsByTagName() returns an array, so you should select the first item by [0]

assigning CSS properties using JS is outdated, better adding classes that apply changes as I did.

by assigning a class to parent you can apply changes to all of it's childs.

Why were you using css inside html while you had a css file, (what i thought by looking at your html : You don't need to use css inside element to apply it's changes.)


const svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];

svg.addEventListener('click', () => {
svg.classList.add('active')
})
     div {
          border: 1px solid #000000;
     }
     .text {
          font-family: Sans-serif;
          font-size: x-large;
          fill: #D3D3D3;
          opacity: 0;
          cursor: none;
      }
      svg.active .text{
         opacity: 1;
         fill: #000;
      }
<div id='paper'>
  <svg version='1.1'width="595" height="842" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <text x="70" y="97" class="text">W</text>
    <text x="70" y="100" class="text">W</text>
    <text x="70" y="103.5" class="text">W</text>
    <text x="70" y="107" class="text">W</text>
    <text x="70" y="110.5" class="text">W</text>
    <text x="70" y="114" class="text">W</text>
    <text x="70" y="117.5" class="text">W</text>
    <text x="70" y="121" class="text">W</text>
    <text x="70" y="124.5" class="text">W</text>
    <text x="70" y="128" class="text">W</text>
    <text x="70" y="131.5" class="text">W</text>
  </svg>
</div>





Hope I helped ^_^

Your last point of comment helped! I thought of that before submitting my questions here, so yes, all should be put in the css file. Thanks!
